# Linknyc free public wifi repeater/bridge

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, dd-wrt, wifi-configuration, wireless-bridge

I live in NYC and may be able to reach a [linknyc](https://www.link.nyc/) hotspot in my new apartment. I'm wondering if I can use this as a source for a wireless repeater/bridge (not sure which is correct) for free internet!

I'd want my own local network so I think I want a [repeater](https://www.flashrouters.com/blog/2011/10/19/what-is-the-difference-between-client-bridge-wireless-repeater-modes-in-dd-wrt/)?

I currently have a nighthawk router with ddwrt installed. Would I be able to connect my router the linknyc private connection (I've read it uses HotSpot 2.0 and WPA) and connect my other devices to it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have all the answers to your questions, but can share my recent experience trying to link an extender to a LinkNYC kiosk. After the new tower was lit up cater-corner to my apartment I installed a Nighthawk extender that I know works with other signals. I get only a moderate signal from the tower but enough to slowly load webpages (but not to stream video). I was able to connect the extender to LinkNYC but after repeated attempts was unable to get internet. In my WiFi drop down it said "Connected, but no internet". I assume the reason is that the signal is too weak here. Provided you do get a strong signal, I don't know if you can create a local network. LinkNYC HotSpot 2.0 only works at present with a limited number of devices, mostly Apple phones.